# UIPageViewController with multiple UIViewController with header and bottom bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I did a `UIPageViewController` with multiple `UIViewController`. And now, I need to add a fixed `UIView` in top and in bottom in `UIPageViewController`...

There's my code:

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create it.
    self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    // Point the datasource back to this UIViewController.
    self.pageController.dataSource = self;

    // Assuming you have a SomePageViewController which extends UIViewController so you can do custom things.


    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    if(!self.roteirosView)
        self.roteirosView = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RoteirosView"];

    self.initialViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.roteirosView];

    // animated:NO is important so the view just pops into existence.
    // direction: doesn't matter because it's not animating in.
    [self.pageController setViewControllers:self.initialViewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    // Tell the child view to get ready
    [self.pageController willMoveToParentViewController:self];

    // Actually add the child view controller
    [self addChildViewController:self.pageController];

    // Don't forget to add the new root view to the current view hierarchy!
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageController.view];

    // And make sure to activate!
    [self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
}

- (UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(int)i {
    // Asking for a page that is out of bounds??
    if (i<0) {
        return nil;
    }
    if (i>=MAX_PAGES) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Assuming you have SomePageViewController.xib
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    if (i == 0) {
        if(!self.roteirosView)
            self.roteirosView = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RoteirosView"];
        return self.roteirosView;
    }
    else {
        if(!self.pertoView)
            self.pertoView = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PertoView"];
        return self.pertoView;
    }
}


- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    UIViewController *p = (UIViewController *)viewController;
    if ([p isKindOfClass:[PertoViewController class]]) {
        return [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    }
    else {
        return [self viewControllerAtIndex:MAX_PAGES]; // permanece na mesma página
    }

}


- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    UIViewController *p = (UIViewController *)viewController;
    if ([p isKindOfClass:[PertoViewController class]]) {
        return [self viewControllerAtIndex:MAX_PAGES]; // permanece na mesma página
    }
    else {
        return [self viewControllerAtIndex:1];
    }
}
```

In my `UIStoryBoard` I have HomesViewController which is my `UIPageViewController`, PertoViewController and RoteirosViewController. Both `UIViewControllers` add in `UIPageViewController`.

Comment: What exactly the problem is?

Comment: I can scroll and change the UIViewControllers, but It has the size of screen...I need to add these UIViewController inside a content to show my top and bottom UIView which I have in UIPageViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in viewDidAppear of the UIPagerViewController class add the 2 UIViews you want to add this should add the new views over already loaded views the 2 view controller.

if that didn't work for you make sure you add the 2 view controller also by code in not Storyboard and make sure to add them first then add the 2 views header and bottom one to make sure they are over the screens

hope this answer can help you and good luck

Comment: But when I set the frame of views, doesn't work .The views area always added in position 0,0

Comment: @ladessa-ios let me see how you init the view please are you you you init it with frame and give them the frame you want

Comment: Sorry, I do everything again and it works great!  Thanks a lot!